# How can I find the ID of a tag synonym?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

To find the ID of a tag, I can navigate to that tag's Tagged Questions or Tag Wiki page and click improve tag info or edit tag, and see the tag ID in the URL:

```
http://domain.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/[tag_id]
```

However, trying to navigate to a synonym's "Tagged Questions" page redirects to the synonym, and not the original tag.  How can I find the tag ID of a redirected synonym?

Comment: Just curious: what do you need the tag ID for?

Comment: @Glorfindel no good reason, really.  Just was wondering if this information was available, and what would happen if you tried to edit the wiki of a tag synonym.

Comment: You will just edit the old tag wiki of the synonym: check the edit page of [itext](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/10881) and [itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/16611) which have been synonymized yesterday (so I could find both tag IDs in SEDE).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There *isn't* necessarily an ID. Tag synonyms are based on tag *name*, not ID; thus, there are [thousands of synonyms](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/517221) that map one name to another, but where the "source" name doesn't correspond to any tag currently in the system.

In cases where the ID does exist though, it's trivial to look this up via SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/517222/tag-ids-for-synonyms

With this in hand, you can now find "orphaned" tag wikis: https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/7715

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a different way instead of using SEDE.

If you navigate to the `/tags` page on any Stack Exchange site and hover over a tag, you will see an "edit" link appear.  Clicking that link will take you to the "edit tag wiki" page for that tag (even if the tag is a synonym), revealing the tag ID in the URL.

Here's an example on [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/).  Navigate to the [Popular Tags tab](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=popular) and search "cassette."  Clicking on the cassette tag will redirect to the [cassette-tape](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cassette-tape) page, but clicking edit on the cassette tag will take you to the cassette [edit tag wiki](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/20) page, revealing that it is tag 20.